# Can I format %property{NDC} in log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

In log4net, we stack NDC like

```
using (var scope1 = ThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push("Foo"))
{
    using (var scope2 = ThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push("Bar"))
    {
        _logger.Debug("Zar");
    }
}
```

If I have setting in `log4net.config` like `<conversionPattern value="%property{NDC} - %message" />`, the output should be `Foo Bar - Zar`.

May I know if there anyway to format `%property{NDC}`? e.g. `Foo => Bar - Zar`